# How to handle an asterisk * in an id selector

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have PHP code generating a row of buttons for the user to click, with each button corresponding to the grade of a student. The PHP also generates the jquery needed to cause a button click to randomly select a student with that grade:

```
echo "<div id='targetGradeButtons' class='testing'>Randomly select student with target grade: " ;

foreach ($uniquetarget as $i => $target) {

    echo "<button id='target-$target'>$target</button> " ; // Generate button for randomly selecting students with certain target
    // Create jquery to handle button clicks
    echo "<script>
        $('#target-$target').click(function(){

            randomName('target', '$target');
        });
    </script>"  ;

}

echo "</div>" ;
```

This works perfectly for most grades. However, it doesn't work for A* grades. The random name selector part of it works fine when I hard code A* as the grade, so the problem is with the code above failing to successfully select the #target-A* button. I believe this is because * is a special character. How can I get around this?

Using PHP functions to automatically add escape characters (backslashes), seems not to help.

Comment: Putting special characters in IDs is a bad idea. They're legal, but will make referencing them in CSS and jQuery selectors more complicated. I suggest you convert `$target` to some other format first.

Comment: What do you mean by some other format? Encode it in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than bind a separate handler to each ID, I suggest you give them all the same class, and bind a single handler to the class. It can then get the ID from the target element.

```
echo "<div id='targetGradeButtons' class='testing'>Randomly select student with target grade: " ;
foreach ($uniquetarget as $i => $target) { 
    echo "<button id='target-$target' class='target'>$target</button> " ; // Generate button for randomly selecting students with certain target
}
echo "</div>" ;

// Create jquery to handle button clicks
echo "<script>
$('.target').click(function(){
    randomName('target', this.id.split('-')[1]);
});
</script>"  ;
```

Comment: That also works nicely, with a tiny tweak:

`<button id='$target'...`

All in all, it seems a bit tidier than the other answer

Comment: I added a different tweak. Split the ID in the event handler.

Comment: Is that just to ensure a unique ID? Could be handy, actually, since I have code further down that does much the same thing, but for current grades instead of target grades (so the id would be `current-$current`.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[id=\"target-$target\"')
```

Comment: Don't escape the quotes.

Comment: Don't they need to be escaped since it's in the php code?

Comment: Right, didn't realize the context.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I'll accept the answer ASAP. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using exact id match selector.

```
$('[id="target-A*"]')
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1a6mwb13/3/